# OS X: Reassign the Trackpad Button

Tags: macos, touchpad

I have an iBook G4 with 10.5.7 installed and I would like to change the behavior of the trackpad button so it acts as a Menu Key.  I can select by tapping the trackpad.  Sounds simple enough, can't find an answer though.

Anyone know how I can achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can change the behaviour of the trackpad button without affecting the behaviour of tapping the trackpad. I believe tapping on the track pad just invokes whatever action is assigned to the trackpad button.

Answer (score 1):

Because both signals are not mixed on the hardware level, it surely is possible given you can change the right parts in the system. Which doesn't mean it's easy.

I don't know for OSX 10.5.7, but OSX 10.6+ has a multitouch private API which allows you to intercept click and tap events from the device from a software. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to expose the physical clicks and it's not well documented.

Here is a program that re-interprets 3-finger taps as a middle click (only source): https://github.com/cl3m/MiddleClick This could be the foundation for what you want to do. Either find a way to get notified of the click or change your requirement to 3-finger taps.

**Update: I was a bit fast reading the code, thought differentiating clicks from taps was possible.**